"How to use JavaScript to detect which page is open so it can assign a class to the correct element?
I am creating side menu, and I am trying to create javascript, that detect on what page I am on, and to add class active to the right element.
I have this html:
<div>
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="link1.html" className="menuLink"> Page 1 </a></li>
    <li> <a href="link2.html" className="menuLink"> Page 2 </a></li>
    <li> <a href="link3.html" className="menuLink"> Page 3 </a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

And ChatGpt sugestet this code for javascipt:
const currentPath = window.location.pathname;

document.querySelectorAll('.menuLink').forEach((link) => {
    
    if (link.getAttribute('href') === currentPath) {
        link.classList.add('active'); 
    }
});

Sadly it is not working. Any sugestions? Thank you.

ChatGPT is incorrect for one small reason (also a good example of why you should not use AI for coding but actually require knowledge about coding). window.location.pathname returns the path to the current file with a leading slash /. However, the href of your anchors has no leading slash. So you need to add them to the href to work correctly.
It will also only work if all the files are directly within the root folder!


const currentPath = window.location.pathname;

document.querySelectorAll('nav a').forEach((link) => {
  link.classList.toggle('active', (link.getAttribute('href') === currentPath)); 
});
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="/link1.html" class="menuLink"> Page 1 </a></li>
    <li> <a href="/link2.html" class="menuLink"> Page 2 </a></li>
    <li> <a href="/link3.html" class="menuLink"> Page 3 </a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>



You can use classList.toggle() to add the class depending on the condition. So you don't need an if statement.
